# Removing a video uploaded to the main page on Moodle 2.010

Tags: moodle

all,

I can't figure this out! I uploaded a video a very long time ago to this site and it still appears on the main page, and I can't find the file anywhere. Any ideas?

http://johnkomlos.com/moodle

On the left under 'Home' there is a link to 'Lily the dog test' that I can't seem to get rid of.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I can't see any videos at the moment - So I assume you've fixed the issue. However, just for future reference of other users:

Your homepage is essentially a course list. The course list renders the description of the course. You probably inserted a video into a course's description.

To remove a video from said location, go on that course, and go to  Course administration --> Edit settings.

Under the "Description" box, remove the video.

Your alternative option is to stop the theme from rendering the course's description as a whole. You will find that type of options under the "Appearance" list in Moodle's admin block.

Comment: Well, I found a way to hide the video by hiding the left-hand navigation altogether.

I don't see 'Edit Settings' under course Course Administration, however. Is it under another sub-category?

Comment: Hi, Ah, you didn't mention that the video was in the side bar... If the video was in the left hand navigation rather than the main content part, then it was probably a block, not a course description. To edit blocks, you turn editing, and then you click on the edit icon above the block containing the video. I can't give you an exact description of what this icon will look like because it's different from theme to theme, but it's most likely going to be a pencil icon.